# how to update values automatically from database

Tags: java, ajax

i am doing mvc project and i want to update the web page automatically when the web page is loaded.

Ex: web page 1 is used to add the companies in database,web page 2 is used to delete the companies,when the web page 2 is loaded automatically in the web page 2 select box should appear with the values as company names to delete the companies from database.

i am expecting to use ajax here to automatically load the data but problem is to fetch the data from database i am using java class instead of jsp or servlet,so i am not understanding how to fetch the data from java class and use to load automatically in web page 2 for the select box.

Please help me on the same.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please be more specific for the task under-hand.

Comment: i have two web pages and one java class for database connection. The  web page 1 is 

to add the companies in database and web page 2 having the select box. The web page 

2 having select box which displays the values ie company names which are added in 

database through web page 1 should come automatically without loading the page,so i 

feel ajax we can use but i am not understanding how to use the ajax code to fetch 

the values from java class(which fetch the database) and display in web page 2 

select box.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you have to use servlet, with which ajax will interact to fetch the values on page2. In servlet, you can call you java class to make database connection. Hope it helps!

Comment: could you please give and example